# Regular Expression Pattern matching issue

Tags: javascript, regex

Not a lot of experience in RegEx stuff.

I have the following in java script which works perfectly fine.

The following pattern is used allow only alpha numeric

```
var valid = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test("a"); // returns true
var valid = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test("@"); // returns false
```

I am using the pattern part "^[A-Za-z0-9]" in some other places of the code and was asked to use the part "^[A-Za-z0-9]" in a variable and use it so that it is not repetitive. The following is a modification to the above:

```
var regExPart= "^[A-Za-z0-9]";
var regExString = ("/" + regExPart+ "+$/".replace(/\"/g, "")); // replacing the quotes
var regExp = new RegExp(regExString); // results in /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
var valid = regExp.test(charValue); // charValue could be any keyvalue "a" or "@"

//the above returns false for "a" 
//the above returns false for "@"
```

I am writing this in a keypress event to allow only alpha numeric

```
keypressValidation: function (e) {
var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which: event.keyCode;
var charValue = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
var valid = return /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(charValue);
if (!valid) 
{
    //prevent default (don't allow/ enter the value)
}
```

Not sure why. What am I missing in this. Need to **return true for "a" and false for "@" for both the approaches.** Any help/ suggestion would be of great help. Thank in advance.

Comment: I usually like DRY-ness, but IMO it's not something to try for across *multiple separate* regular expressions unless the repeated pattern is *long*. (also note that your character set simplifies to `[a-z\d]` with the `i` flag)

Comment: Could you provide what the content of `charValue` is ?

Comment: Also, do you only need to check if your character is `a` ? Why use a regex in that case ?

Comment: @Nicolas I am writing this as a part of keypress validation in java script to now allow user to enter only alpha numeric values. Updated my post.

Comment: Just use `RegExp` constructor [correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `RegExp` class constructor, you do not need to specify forward slashes `/`.

```js
var regExPart= "^[A-Za-z0-9]";
var regExp = new RegExp(regExPart + "+$"); // results in /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/

console.log('a', regExp.test('a'))
console.log('@', regExp.test('@'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a must to contain '/'s in regexp

`new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z]$").test('a')`

return `true`

`new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z]$").test('@')`

return `false`

So just do

`var rex="^[0-9a-zA-Z]$"`

And you can use it anywhere. Tested in Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example using your regex of what it should do, i think the way you were building your regex was not helping. You don't need to create a string and then create a new regex object , you can use `/regex part/`.
Anyways here is a working example.

```js
function keypress(e) {
  // Get the current typed key
  var keynum = e.key;
  // this regex only allow character between a and z and 0 and 9
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
  // we check if the current key matches our regex
  if(!keynum.match(regex) ) {
    // it doesn't ? well we stop the event from happening
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="keypress(event)">
```